# How to render after add item in object

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hi I have a question about page render
I have a Data define in state and its structure like below

```
this.state = {
     Data: this.props.navigation.getParam('Data', 'error')
   };
```

```
[{Name: 'Jason',
 Tel: '000000'},
{Name: 'Lily',
 Tel: '001255'},
{Name: 'Henry',
 Tel: '088000'},
]
```

I call API to add items for each object and I want to let the Data like below

```
[{Name: 'Jason',
Tel: '000000',
Addr: 'dfsfsdgdrtesf'},
{Name: 'Lily',
Tel: '001255',
Addr: 'rgrhrerger'},
{Name: 'Henry',
Tel: '088000',
Addr: 'dfsfsdgdrrgrgtesf'},
]
```

I do this in the 
'''
 async componentDidMount() {

```
for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(this.state.Data).length; i++) {
  await Call_Some_API() => {

    this.state.Data[i].Addr = (Object.keys(jsonData.Other).length + 1).toString();
    this.setState(this.state.Data);
  });
}
console.log(this.state.Data)
```

}
'''
console.log(this.state.Data) is correct!
but I can not get the Addr in my component even if I call this.setState(this.state.Data).

I want to show the Addr but it always empty
It like read old Data not the new one or maybe my method is not right.
Give me a help! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can not get the Addr in my component

Because you are mutating state with this line:

```
   this.state.Data[i].Addr = (Object.keys(jsonData.Other).length + 1).toString();
```

Something like this should work:

```
for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(this.state.Data).length; i++) {
  await Call_Some_API() => {

    const addr = (Object.keys(jsonData.Other).length + 1).toString();
    let tempState = [...this.state.Data];
    tempState[i] = {...tempState[i], "Addr": addr};
    this.setState({ Data: tempState });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `this.setState({ Data: this.state.Data });`.

There is more info in the [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) documentation on the react docs.

Also you probably should clone the state before changing it as mentioned on the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state):

> Never mutate `this.state` directly, as calling `setState()` afterwards may
>   replace the mutation you made. Treat `this.state` as if it were
>   immutable.

Answer (score 0):

You should not change the state directly, instead you should use `setState` function to do that.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works.

```
componentDidMount(){
    Call_API.then(
      res => {
        this.setState( prevState => {
          res.data.map( addr => {
            prevState.map( item => {
               item['Addr'] = addr
            })
          })
        })
      }
    )
}
```